# How to execute a script only once, immediately after ALL network interfaces are up in OpenSUSE?

Tags: networking, scripting, opensuse, interface, ifconfig

I run Opensuse 12.2.

I have 3 network interfaces, eth[012]

The interfaces are configured in /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-eth[012]

I want to execute a script immediately after ALL three interfaces are 'up'.

Adding

```
POST_UP_SCRIPT="/path/to/script.sh"
```

to ifcfg-eth[012] executes the script after any ONE interface is up.

Placing the script in

```
/etc/sysconfig/network/if-up.d/script.sh
```

executes the script multiple times - once after EACH interface is up.

How do I execute the script ONLY ONCE, immediately after the last interface is brought up?